# Wrong formatting returned from OpenAI API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I using OpenAI's API from Marketing Cloud, and trying to get a localized response, but I'm running into formatting issues, which I don't seem to be able to solve.

Here is my request:

```
    <script runat="server">
        Platform.Load("Core", "1");
    try {
    
        var contentType = 'application/json';
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer ******************"]; //apikey
    
        var jsonBody = '{"model": "gpt-4","messages":[';
        jsonBody += '{"role": "user", "content": "write a short text with Danish special characters"}';
        jsonBody += '],"temperature": 0.5,"max_tokens": 1000}';
    
     
    
        var requestUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
    
        var request = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, jsonBody, headerNames, headerValues);
        Write('response: ' + request.Response);

    } catch (e) {
Write("Exception occured: " +e+"<br>");
} 
    </script>
```

Here is my response where I get the JSON object back which should contain special characters like "ø" and "å" but instead they are returned like "Ã¸" and "Ã¥".

```
{ "id": "chatcmpl-8fTyW3AS4toQQbdmk6kJBq5S3ETyw", "object": "chat.completion", "created": 1704897364, "model": "gpt-4-0613", "choices": [ { "index": 0, "message": { "role": "assistant", "content": "Jeg elsker at lÃ¦se bÃ¸ger. Det er en fantastisk mÃ¥de at tilbringe min fritid pÃ¥. Min yndlingsbog er \"Den lille prins\". Det er en smuk historie, der lÃ¦rer os om venskab, kÃ¦rlighed og tab. Jeg synes, at alle bÃ¸r lÃ¦se den mindst Ã©n gang i deres liv." }, "logprobs": null, "finish_reason": "stop" } ], "usage": { "prompt_tokens": 15, "completion_tokens": 90, "total_tokens": 105 }, "system_fingerprint": null }
```

I just cannot get it to interpret the response in the correct format, it looks like it's not interpreting it as UTF-8.
I have tried multiple things, but I can't get it to work.
Doing the exact same in Postman gives me a completely fine response with special characters in the response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying the charset in the contentType?

```
var contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
```

Ref: [stackoverflow.com/a/9254967/812377](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254967/812377)

Comment: I actually tried running the SSJS written by Nikolai, and see same issue, even when adding charset to the content type header. I suspect there might be an issue with the endpoint itself, as per [this thread](https://community.openai.com/t/gpt-4-1106-preview-is-not-generating-utf-8/482839/6)

Comment: Yes that's one of the things I tried, as well as multiple unsuccessful attempts to decode it afterwards.

Comment: Also [this thread](https://community.openai.com/t/api-does-not-support-utf-8-encoding/98400), indicates there may be some workaround possible.  Trick may be getting on of the workarounds to function in the archaic SSJS infrastructure of SFMC.

Comment: I did see that post as well, but I don't see how I can select bodyBytes as that doesn't seem to be part of the response. 

I also tried to ask it to base64 encode the reply before sending it, but that results in some terrible responses.

And I tried asking it to URlencode special characters, which works from ChatGPT UI, but the API just ignores this request.